# Correct way of handling window.onclick

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm following the example of creating custom Modal:
[link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp)

This is the code snippet:

```
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close its  
window.onclick = function(event) {
 if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

What is the correct way to implement that in an Angular 5 Project?

Comment: more code about this will be helpful for understanding.

Comment: hi, I put "link" the code there is exacly the code that I have (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use HostListener for handling event:

```
@HostListener('button:click', ['$event'])
methodToExecuteOnEvent(event){
// your code goes here...
}
```

More about it on the [doc](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener)